# Maximizing page usage for a table

Tags: tables, dimensions

I'm printing a table enclosing 4 other data tables, one per page, and would like to maximize the space available by reducing the margins as much as possible.  I still need the page number, but wonder if it can be made to take minimal space.  My table contains `resizebox`'ed cells, so I wonder what surrounding mechanics can be employed to get rid of most of the margins specifically for those pages with such tables?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `newgeometry` macro from the `geometry` package to change the margins to suit.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[hmargin=3cm,showframe]{geometry}
\begin{document}
L1
\newgeometry{left=3cm,right=1cm,bottom=0.1cm}
\savegeometry{L2}
L2 (new, saved)
15
\restoregeometry
L1 (restored)
\newgeometry{margin=1cm,includefoot}
L3 (new)
\loadgeometry{L2}
L2 (loaded)
\end{document}
```

You can also adjust margins by writing your own macros. For example see my answer at [How to switch between two different marginparwidth size?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/6402/how-to-switch-between-two-different-marginparwidth-size)

Comment: :-) I was just typing the same and then "A new answer has been submitted" ...