# How to switch between two margin sizes?

Tags: indentation, double-sided, tufte

> **This question led to a new package:**
>   [`fullwidth`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/fullwidth)

This is a followup to [a similar question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/6402/how-to-switch-between-two-different-marginparwidth-size). The idea is to switch between two different margin sizes. The answer provided by @godbyk work very well. However, it is difficult if you are using an asymmetric page layout (e.g. `\documentclass[twoside]{article}` and the `fullwidth` environment spans over two pages. Is it possible to make it work in these cases, too?

The memoir manual states:

> Note that the `adjustwidth` environment applies to complete paragraphs;
>   you can’t change the width of part of a paragraph except for hanging
>   paragraphs or more esoterically via `\parshape`. Further, if the
>   adjusted paragraph crosses a page boundary the margin changes are
>   constant; a paragraph that is, say, wider at the right on the first
>   page will also be wider at the right as it continues onto the
>   following page.

So, how to do it esoterically ;)

MWE:

```
\documentclass[twoside]{article}

\usepackage{changepage}% provides the adjustwidth environment

% The following code should be used *after* any changes to the margins and
% page layout are made (e.g., after the geometry package has been loaded).
\newlength{\fullwidthlen}
\setlength{\fullwidthlen}{\marginparwidth}
\addtolength{\fullwidthlen}{\marginparsep}

\newenvironment{fullwidth}{%
  \begin{adjustwidth*}{}{-\fullwidthlen}%
}{%
  \end{adjustwidth*}%
}

\usepackage{lipsum}% provides dummy text

\begin{document}

\lipsum[1]

\begin{fullwidth}
    \lipsum[2-10]
\end{fullwidth}

\lipsum[3]

\end{document}
```

Comment: Would you be able to elaborate a little more on what you mean by "an asymmetric design breaks on a new page"?

Comment: @Andy I am not sure if I understand the question also. Could you post a sketch of what you are trying to achieve. Memoir when referring to `esoteric` mean for paragraphs only, i.e., you can make a sort of a shaped hole in a paragraph.

Comment: The OP is trying to adjust the left and right margins of a specific block using `adjustwidth`. The block of text should accommodate page breaking and be able to switch between adjusting for the *left* (`\marginparwidth+\marginparsep`) on even pages, but for the same amount on the *right* for odd pages. So, the `adjustwidth` environment should switch accordingly from one margin adjustment to another, depending on the current page. Am I correct @Andy?

Comment: The problem is particularly highlighted if you add `\begin{fullwidth} \lipsum[2-10] \end{fullwidth}` after `\lipsum[3]`; perhaps the OP could do so.

Comment: @werner, yes, you are correct.

Comment: @Werner: This is only possible if the contents is save in separate boxes to align them on odd or even pages.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

The new package [`fullwidth`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/fullwidth) is uploaded to CTAN. The development status is available on [`github`](https://github.com/marcodaniel/fullwidth).

```
\setcounter{errorcontextlines}{999}
\documentclass[twoside]{article}
\usepackage{showframe,lipsum}
\usepackage[innermargin=-2.0cm,]{fullwidth}
\begin{document}
\lipsum

%\clearpage
\begin{fullwidth}[width=\linewidth+2cm]
Start\par
\lipsum[1] \lipsum \lipsum
ENDE
\end{fullwidth}
\end{document}
```

---

Are you looking for somethink like the following example?

```
\documentclass[twoside]{article}
%\usepackage{showframe}
\usepackage{mdframed}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}

\lipsum[1]

\begin{mdframed}[outermargin=\dimexpr-\marginparwidth-\marginparsep\relax,innermargin=0pt]
    \lipsum[2-10]
\end{mdframed}

\lipsum[3]
\end{document}
```

Comment: Yes, this looks very good. I guess, it would be easy to not show the frame, `[hidealllines=true]` shifts the box a little. Could you estimate how much of the 1000 lines in the package would be needed to achieve the behavior, without the options and other goodies you have in `mdframes`.

Comment: @Andy: Based on my package I can create a new one which only sets the left/right or inner/outer margin. But not in the next five minutes ;-)

Comment: @MarcoDaniel This works really nicely, but I tried using it for the bibliography ( since those are long, and don't need a large margin, since there won't be any sidenotes there). Well it doesn't work, and the compilation never finishes due to some endless loop. Using `[nobreak=true]{mdframed}` recommended [here](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/43236/endless-loop-with-mdframed) does not work either (first page of bibliography that still runs of the page is typeset).