# Changing textwidth with adjustwidth* in memoir

Tags: page-breaking, indentation, memoir

I'm using `memoir` with non-equal left and right margins and encounter a problem when I use the `adjustwidth*` environment to get three equally spaced columns with equal margins in the index. According to the [`memoir` manual](http://mirror.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/memoir/memman.pdf) (bottom of p. 144 of latest version dated 2011/03/06), the changes do not get changed properly across page breaks. That is, if the right (outer) margin is shifted outward on an odd (recto) page, the same will be true on the next (even/verso) page. But this is not what I need.

Furthermore, I'm a little confused by the fact that the `memoir` manual states (p. 340) that `changepage` contains code identical to memoir, but the `\changetext` command provided by `changepage` is not available in memoir. At the moment, it appears to me that the `\changetext` command provided by `changepage` is what I need to use, but I'm wondering whether there's a way to do all this inside `memoir` without an additional package.

Comment: At the moment, as far as I know, this is not possible and would require additional packages. @MarcoDaniel provides a work-around in his answer to [How to switch between two margin sizes?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/34368/how-to-switch-between-two-margin-sizes) - it uses the [`mdframed`](http://ctan.org/pkg/mdframed) package with a similarly-named environment. He also suggested writing it up as a separate/stand-alone package (perhaps called `fullwidth`) in [chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/2424310#2424310) recently.

Comment: I do not think the `changepage` additions have made it back into `memoir` (different maintainers). `adjustwidth` is implemented using a list and thus the adjustment goes wrong at a page break when there is uneven margins.

Comment: Thanks for the clarifications. At the moment, I just use \changetext as mentioned in my question. This does what I need it to do.

Comment: Perhaps the solution posted by Peter Wilson in [comp.text.tex](http://tinyurl.com/79yo4dm) can be adapted to your problem.

Comment: Er, I don't think `memoir` supports three-column indexes, anyway.

Comment: @jon I know it's pretty old but do you think it is possible to write an answer using Peter Wilson's remark in c.t.t.?

Answer (score 4):

First you have to consider the effect of changing the margins mid-document. Is it necessary to initiate such a change in the layout mid-document?

At the moment, as far as I know, this is not possible and would require additional packages. Marco Daniel provides a work-around in his answer to [How to switch between two margin sizes?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/34368/5764) - it uses the [`mdframed` package](http://ctan.org/pkg/mdframed) with a similarly-named environment. His [`fullwidth` package](http://ctan.org/pkg/fullwidth) might also be of interest here.

Alternatively, Boris' [`adjmulticol` package](http://ctan.org/pkg/adjmulticol) knows about two-side margins and could potentially provide a solution to your problem. From the [`adjmulticol` documentation](http://mirror.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/adjmulticol/adjmulticol.pdf):

> One of the common requests from the book designers is the possibility
>   to change the margins of the text in the middle of the page. The
>   standard LaTeX `list` environment does exactly this. Thus it is not
>   surprising that many packages creatively use this tool to change the
>   layout. An example is the [`changepage`
>   package](http://ctan.org/pkg/changepage). Unfortunately this approach
>   has a serious drawback: a list sets the margins globally. If the
>   material is split between the pages, the margins on the first page
>   are repeated on all the subsequent pages. While this is fine for
>   one-side printing, it leads to a catastrophe for the two-sided one,
>   [...]
>
> To remedy this problem, we need a completely different approach: we
>   need to change the output routine. This is done in this package.
>
> Since the text with the special layout is often typeset in the
>   multicolumn mode, we load the [`multicol`
>   package](http://ctan.org/pkg/multicol) and patch it to provide two
>   changes:
>
> 1. Margins changes, persistent over the pages.
> 2. The possibility of an one-column "`\multicolumn`" layout. Of course, this layout does not make sense in the context of the original
>      `multicol` package, but is useful when the margins are changed.