# Force a block of text to be impervious to page breaks

Tags: page-breaking

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Unbreakable block](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/4471/unbreakable-block)

I have a block of text (possibly comprising many paragraphs) near the end of a page.  The page break is being inserted in the middle of this block--how do I prevent that?  (How do I tell LaTeX that this block of text needs to always stay together on the same page?)

This question should apply to all formats, but in my case I am using the `memoir` class, and am willing to include any necessary packages.

Comment: Of course you're willing to accept a badly filled page.

Comment: Yes, that's definitely an unavoidable side-effect.

Comment: You could just wrap it into a `\begin{minipage}{\linewidth}...\end{minipage}` environment.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you wrap the contents within a `minipage` then TeX will put that block on the next page if it does not fit on the current page.

In the example below, the text in red is on Page 2. But if you remove the `minipage` environment by commentig out the `\begin{minipage}{\linewidth}` and `\end{minipage}`, then the text will be on Pages 1 and 2.

### Note:

- There is a problem if the text within the `minipage` does not fit in one page.
- As egreg commented there may be problem with spacing depending on how you are using this. See [How to keep a constant baselineskip when using minipages (or \parboxes)?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/34971/how-to-keep-a-constant-baselineskip-when-using-minipages-or-parboxes) for more details.

### Code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}% for dummy text
\usepackage{xcolor}
\begin{document}
\lipsum[1-4]% dummy text to get towards bottom of page
\noindent
\begin{minipage}{\linewidth}% Following stays together
    \color{red}
    \lipsum[1-2]
\end{minipage}
\end{document}
```

Comment: The interline spacing after the `minipage` won't be uniform.

Comment: and the minipage will set the glue (vertical stretch if any) so that it doesn't participate with other glue on the page.

Comment: Thanks!  What is the difference between `\begin{minipage}{\lindwidth}` (what you wrote) and `\begin{minipage}{\textwidth}`?

Comment: Basically `\textwidth` is the full width on the page between the margins, where `\linwidth` adjusts for multiple columns, lists, etc. See [difference between textwidth linewidth and hsize](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/16942/difference-between-textwidth-linewidth-and-hsize) for a more detailed discussion.

Comment: As I just commented here http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/38345/9757, is it possible to define a macro for the `fullwidth` environment, so that whenever I write `\begin{fullwidth}`, LaTeX does `\begin{minipage}{\linewidth} \begin{fullwidth}[width=\linewidth+4cm] \medskip`; and whenever I write `\end{fullwidth}`, LaTeX does `\medskip \end{minipage} \end{fullwidth}`? Thanks!

Comment: @jamaicanworm: This seems like a new question.