# put ending text at the beginning of next page

Tags: positioning, page-breaking

I have some text at the end of my page and I would put it at the beginning of the next page.which could be the best way to have this result?

Comment: doesn't `\newpage` work?

Comment: yes it worked.thanks.since I'm a newbie I didn't know this command

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As ArTourter pointed out, the command `\newpage` should work.

[This webpage](http://www.personal.ceu.hu/tex/breaking.htm) has a nice overview of the many ways to start new lines and start new pages, including an explanation of the difference between `\newpage` and `\pagebreak`.

You might also want to read the answers to [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/736/9757).

Comment: and opposite event?If I would not put a part of text to the other page which is the command?

Comment: @Mazzy I have actually asked that [same question](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/44900/9757) before!  See [this answer](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/4472/9757) for some possible solutions.