# Tufte Fullwidth Bibliography across pages

Tags: biblatex, mdframed, double-sided, tufte, fullwidth

I am trying to print the bibliography in a `tufte-book` using the whole width of the page, since I don't intend to put marginalia into the bibliography.

Edit: I am using an updated version of `tufte` that is not yet on CTAN, otherwise it is incompatible with biblatex.

The problem is that the `fullwidth` environment does not work across pages. I came across a possible solution [here](http://code.google.com/p/tufte-latex/issues/detail?id=8), however, as is mentioned there, this also shifts the page header, effectively ruining the layout (or forcing me to layout the page without headers, which would work, but means admitting defeat)

I found a second, better solution [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/34368/how-to-switch-between-two-margin-sizes) using the `mdframed` environment, and this one seems to work really nicely, however it seems to only work with "normal" text.
Furthermore, if there is a `\chapter` inside the environment, then the compilation falls into an endless loop. The solution proposed [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/43236/endless-loop-with-mdframed) seems to only amount to effectively disabling the package.

Using `\printbibliography` inside `mdframed` also results in an endless loop. As I found out, writing the MWE attached below, this can be remedied by `[heading=subbibintoc]`.
This way there is no new chapter, ergo no endless loop. However, the output still is wrong, only the first biblabel is printed, with the complete bibliography (without further labels) following.

The page layout is nice though :)

MWE:

```
\documentclass[a4paper, nobib, symmetric, twoside]{tufte-book} % 
%\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage{hyphenat} 
\usepackage[american]{babel}
\usepackage[style=alphabetic, backend=biber]{biblatex}
\usepackage[hidealllines=true]{mdframed}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\bibliography{biblatex-examples}
\begin{document}
\nocite{*}

%Normal Tufte Layout, lots of wasted space, since sidenotes are not needed here
\printbibliography[title=Normal Behaviour]

%First try, either recto or verso fine, the other runs off the page, depending on where bibliography starts
\begin{fullwidth}
\printbibliography[title=First Fullpage Attempt]
\end{fullwidth}

%Second try, works, but header offset as well (see missing pagenumbers)
\makeatletter
\changetext{}{\@tufte@overhang}{-\@tufte@overhang}{}{}
\makeatother
\printbibliography[title=Second Fullpage Attempt]
\makeatletter
\changetext{}{-\@tufte@overhang}{\@tufte@overhang}{}{}
\makeatother

% This works, but only with "normal" text, not with biliography
\begin{mdframed}[outermargin=\dimexpr-\marginparwidth-\marginparsep\relax,innermargin=0pt]
\section{Third Attempt with Normal Text}%works
%\chapter{Third Attempt with Normal Text}%Endless loop
\lipsum[1-20]
\end{mdframed}

% Gives endless loop if uncommented
\begin{mdframed}[outermargin=\dimexpr-\marginparwidth-\marginparsep\relax,innermargin=0pt]
%\printbibliography[title=Third Fullpage Attempt]%Endless Loop
%\printbibliography[heading=subbibintoc, title=Third Fullpage Attempt]%Compiles fine but only gives first bib label, with complete bibliography
\end{mdframed}

\end{document}
```

So, two questions:

- Why is there an endless loop if a new chapter is inside the `mdframed` environment?
- How to get nice output/why is the output different for `\lipsum` and `\printbibliography`

Comment: Well, compilation breaks for other reasons, e.g. hyphenation and `\bibhang` error message

Comment: (I'm using the dev version from [code.google.com](https://code.google.com/p/tufte-latex/source/browse/).) Your second attempt seems to works quite nicely if you don't use `symmetric` (I could not see any adverse effect on the page number).

Comment: @SoundsOfSilence Sorry, I should have mentioned that I also use the dev version mentioned, since otherwise `tufte` is not compatible with `biblatex`, it uses `natbib`.

Comment: @moewe Yes, if using an asymmetric layout, then `fullwidth` works nicely. However, I am not free too chose where the margin is, and it has to be on the outside (Which I think looks nicer in print anyway. For a pdf to be read on screen, the margin can stay on the same side for all pages)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using `tcolorbox` instead of `mdframed` or `fullwidth` finally solved the issue.
Using `grow to right by = \marginparwidth+\marginparsep` on an odd page, and the opposite on an even page, I get (nearly) what I want, without any bugs.
I think the length is not exactly right, but it's close enough for now. (Until someone smarter comes along at least)

```
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}

\begin{tcolorbox}[enhanced, show bounding box, breakable, colback=white, colframe=white, check odd page, toggle left and right, grow to right by=\marginparwidth+\marginparsep, toggle enlargement=evenpage]
\lipsum[1-16]
\end{tcolorbox}
```

Answer (score 1):

Reviving this old question because I found a solution that works better for me,

In the pre-amble, I'll use the geometry package to set the margin size:

`\usepackage{geometry}`
`\geometry{marginparsep=0.5cm, marginparwidth=4.0cm, <other options>}`

then after `\backmatter`, or whenever relevant for you, use:

`\newgeometry{marginparsep=0pt, marginparwidth=0pt, <same other options as before>}`

You could do this on a per-chapter basis if you want.