# minipage within fullwidth

Tags: indentation, minipage, fullwidth

I'm using Marco Daniel's `fullwidth` package, detailed [in this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/34371/9757).  I want all of my text in `fullwidth` to be inseparable (and to begin and end with long black lines), so I am currently doing the following:

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{memoir}

\usepackage[outermargin=-4cm,]{fullwidth}

\begin{document}

\begin{minipage}{\linewidth}
\begin{fullwidth}[width=\linewidth+4cm]
\medskip

This is very long, but because it is in the fullwidth environment,
it extends into the full length of the page
before a line break occurs.

\medskip
\end{fullwidth}
\end{minipage}

\end{document}
```

This works, but it does give me the following warnings:

> " fullwidth uses option nobreak  Warning: \def  on input line 15"
>
> "Package fullwidth Warning: The environment is empty
>   (fullwidth)                 on input line 15."

along with an

> "Overfull \hbox"...

These warning do not occur when I remove the `minipage` command.  What is causing these warning, and how can I get rid of them?

Also, can I define a macro so that whenever I just write `\begin{fullwidth}`, LaTeX will automatically do `\begin{minipage}{\linewidth} \begin{fullwidth}[width=\linewidth+4cm] \medskip`?

UPDATE:

@cmhughes provided a perfect solution to the "define a macro" question.  However, his use of the `nobreak` option in `fullwidth` instead of using `minipage` doesn't work.  Here's the gist of the problem with it:

If I use `[leftmargin = -4cm]` OR `[outermargin = -4cm]`, then the `fullwidth` text extends into the correct margin (the outer margin) on odd pages, and the incorrect margin (the inner margin) on even pages. If I use `[rightmargin = -4cm]` OR `[innermargin = -4cm]`, then the `fullwidth` text extends into the correct margin (the outer margin) on even pages, and the incorrect margin (the inner margin) on odd pages. Herein lies the problem: the `nobreak` option messes up relative positioning, so that `outermargin` and `innermargin` only behave like `leftmargin` and `rightmargin`.

Please read the comments on his answer for a more detailed discussion.  As of now, I'm looking for something that can fix the warnings given by using `minipage`, or that can use the `nobreak` option correctly...

Comment: If no one fixed the problem, what am I supposed to do with the bounty?

Answer (score 8):

I'm not sure I really understand the problem, but if you want to put some unbreakable stuff in fullpage (or anything) I'd have expected the minipage to be inside the environment rather than outside it.

```
\begin{fullwidth}[width=\linewidth+4cm]
\noindent\begin{minipage}{\linewidth}
```

generates no warnings and produces a plausible output.

Comment: Thanks for the help!  That more or less works, but in my big document, I'm now having the following problem:  When the `minipage` forces a `fullwidth` chunk of text to stay together on the same page, for some reason it's creating a page break right after the `fullwidth` ends.  (So the text that comes right after `\end{fullwidth}` somehow starts a new page.)  This produces the warning:  "Package fullwidth Warning: you got a bad break you have to change it manually by changing the text, the space or something else on line 416.  Underfull \vbox (badness 10000) detected at line 416."

Comment: If you have big boxes in your document without enough stretchy space between them, TeX can't find good page breaks. Without seeing the document hard to give advice, sometimes you either need to live with the bad break or re-order your document, or put the big box into a float so that latex can find somewhere more suitable to put it.

Comment: My main document is long and complicated, so unfortunately it wouldn't be feasible to post it here.  The problem is that this error is occurring precisely in those places where `minipage` actually does anything.  When I have text in `fullwidth` that would normally be broken up between pages, this setup spaces the rest of the text on that page in such a way that the `fullwidth` starts on a new page so that it is not broken up (good)--but then the text that follows `fullwidth` begins on a new page, even though there was remaining space on the page with the `fullwidth` text (bad)...

Comment: as far as I can see fullwidth is basically a trivlist environment so as well as changing the margins it has display space before and after it, perhaps that is taking up the space where you expect the following text to go the documentation says there is a skipbelow option which you may want to set to 0. Just guessing...

Comment: Unfortunately that doesn't help.

Comment: `\noindent` was all I needed, actually.

Answer (score 7):

Rather than using a `minipage` to stop the environment from being split, you can use the option `nobreak`.

In addition to this, rather than using `\medskip` you can use the options `innertopmargin` and `innerbottommargin`.

In the code below, I've inserted an artificial `vspace` just to test if the block stays together, and doesn't break across pages

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{memoir}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage[outermargin=-4cm,]{fullwidth}

\begin{document}

\lipsum[1]
\vspace{8.5cm}
\lipsum[1]
\begin{fullwidth}[innermargin=-2cm,width=\linewidth+4cm,nobreak]
This is very long, but because it is in the fullwidth environment,
it extends into the full length of the page
before a line break occurs.
\end{fullwidth}

\end{document}
```

You can create your own environment

```
\newenvironment{myfullwidth}{\begin{fullwidth}[width=\linewidth+4cm,nobreak]}%
{\end{fullwidth}}
```

which can be used as

```
\begin{myfullwidth}
\lipsum[2]
\end{myfullwidth}
```

Comment: The problem is that with the `nobreak` command, the `fullwidth` extends into the wrong margin.  Try compiling your code as an example--now the text in `fullwidth` runs off the page (gets cut off), whereas it did not in my example.  I assume it's getting confused about which margin (left or right) to extend into, since it's not sure what page (even or odd) it's on...

Comment: When I compile your example exactly as it is written (including the use of `outermargin` at the top), the word "of" runs off the page.

Comment: @jamaicanworm sorry for the delay (it seems the site was down for a while)- see my edit to include some compensation using `innermargin`

Comment: Your example now compiles and the text is not cut off--however, the `fullwidth` text now extends into the inner margin, which I do not want.  Again, the problem is that using `nobreak` for some reason switches the direction that the text extends into.  (Using just `\begin{fullwidth}[width=\linwidth+4cm]` (as in my original example, without `nobreak`), the text extends into the correct direction.)

Comment: @jamaicanworm I'm sorry if I have misunderstood. I think you need to use either a combination of `innermargin` and `outermargin` which will respect the `twoside` mode, or if you want absolute positioning, try `leftmargin` and `rightmargin`

Comment: If I use `[leftmargin = -4cm]` OR `[outermargin = -4cm]`, then the `fullwidth` text extends into the correct margin (the outer margin) on odd pages, and the incorrect margin (the inner margin) on even pages.  If I use `[rightmargin = -4cm]` OR `[innermargin = -4cm]`, then the `fullwidth` text extends into the correct margin (the outer margin) on even pages, and the incorrect margin (the inner margin) on odd pages.  Herein lies the problem:  the `nobreak` option messes up relative positioning, so that `outermargin` and `innermargin` only behave like `leftmargin` and `rightmargin`.

Comment: @jamaicanworm: Then it's a bug and you should write me an e-mail.

Comment: @MarcoDaniel The problem should be clear from my previous comment.  Do you need any more details?