# Printing bibliography with biblatex in Tufte-handout fullwidth environment

Tags: biblatex, indentation, tufte

I'm trying to print the bibliography (using biblatex) inside the `fullwidth` environment. But when I place the `\printbibliography` command inside the `fullwidth` environment, every line other than the very first gets indented.

As far I as can tell, `biblatex` prints  bibliographies as follows:

1. The first line of each item is flushed left.
2. Any other line of each item is indented using `\bibhang`.

If I simply place `\printbibliography` at the end of my file, I get the expected behavior:

[image: Default behavior<code>\printbibliography</code>]

If instead I place it inside a `fulldiwth` environment, every line in the bibliography other than the first one gets indented the same amount.

Here's a minimal example

```
\documentclass[nobib]{tufte-handout} 
\usepackage[style=authoryear-comp]{biblatex} 
\begin{filecontents*}{mybib5.bib} 
@MISC{Volkmann, 
  author = {Volkmann, Albert}, 
  title = {My Title}, 
  year = {2005}, 
  addendum={Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, 
sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.} 
} 

@MISC{Caesar, 
  author = {Caesar, Gaius J.}, 
  title = {My long title}, 
  year = {2005}, 
  addendum={Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, 
sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.} 
} 

\end{filecontents*} 
\title{Test} 
\author{Me} 
\bibliography{mybib5} 
\begin{document} 
\maketitle 
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut  aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum. \cite{Volkmann,Caesar} 

\begin{fullwidth} 
\printbibliography 
\end{fullwidth} 
\end{document}
```

The output looks like so: [image: Odd behavior: biblatex and fullwidth environment]

If I set `\parindent` to 0pt right before `\printbibliography`, I get the same result. If instead I set `\bibhang` to 0pt right before `\printbibliography`, so that

```
\begin{fullwidth}
\printbibliography
\end{bibliography}
```

is replaced by:

```
\begin{fullwidth}
\bibhang=0pt
\printbibliography
\end{bibliography}
```

no line in the bibliography is indented:

[image: After setting <code>\bibhang</code> to 0pt]

What I can't get is the default behavior (first line of each item flushed left, every additional line indented) within the `fullwidth` environment.

Any thoughts?

UPDATE: I'm using [version 3.5.2](https://tufte-latex.googlecode.com/svn-history/r173/trunk/tufte-common.def) of `tufte-common.def`.

Comment: My biblatex and natbib hate each other, so I can't even compile this, sorry. :)

Comment: Might want to add that you're using a [revised copy of tufe-common.def](https://tufte-latex.googlecode.com/svn-history/r173/trunk/tufte-common.def). What class layout options are you actually using? The `twoside` and `symmetric` settings complicate the problem.

Comment: Good point, @Audrey. Yeah, I'm using v. 3.5.2. I was not using any options; this was the behavior after compiling the files above with a clean install of v. 3.5.2.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

With the default tufte-latex layout, you can just extend the right margin inside the bibliography environment.

```
\documentclass[nobib]{tufte-handout}
\usepackage{hyphenat}
\usepackage[american]{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage[style=authoryear-comp,autocite=footnote]{biblatex}

\defbibenvironment{bibliography}
  {\list{}{%
     \leftmargin\bibhang
     \itemindent-\leftmargin
     \advance\rightmargin-\marginparwidth
     \advance\rightmargin-\marginparsep
     \itemsep\bibitemsep
     \parsep\bibparsep}}
  {\endlist}
  {\item}

\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}
\begin{document}
Filler text \autocite{companion,ctan,markey,aristotle:poetics,aristotle:rhetoric}.
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image]

With the layout settings `twoside,symmetric` something like tufte-latex's `fullwidth` environment is needed, but it won't work if the bibliography [breaks across pages](http://code.google.com/p/tufte-latex/issues/detail?id=8). For a single bibliography contained in one page, the following should give you proper indentation inside the `fullwidth` environment.

```
\defbibenvironment{bibliography}
  {\list{}{%
     \leftmargin\bibhang
     \itemindent-\leftmargin
     \listparindent\itemindent
     \parsep\bibparsep}}
  {\endlist}
  {\item}
```

The more general case can be [handled using the mdframed package](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/34371/4483) and some spacing trickery with `\AtEveryBibitem`.

```
\documentclass[nobib,twoside,symmetric]{tufte-handout}
\usepackage{hyphenat}
\usepackage[american]{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage[style=authoryear-comp]{biblatex}
\usepackage{mdframed}

\newmdenv[skipabove=3.5ex plus 1ex minus .2ex,% Equal to section title spacing
  innerleftmargin=0pt,innerrightmargin=0pt,%
  innerbottommargin=0pt,innertopmargin=0pt,linewidth=0pt,innermargin=0pt,%
  outermargin=\dimexpr-\marginparwidth-\marginparsep\relax]{mdfullwidth}

\defbibenvironment{bibliography}
  {\list{}{\parsep\bibparsep}}
  {\endlist}
  {\item}

\AtEveryBibitem{\hskip-\bibhang}

\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}
\begin{document}
\null\vfill
One of the most prominent and distinctive features of this style is the
extensive use of sidenotes.\footcite{companion,ctan,markey,aristotle:rhetoric} There is a wide margin to provide ample room for sidenotes and small figures. Any footnotes will automatically be converted to sidenotes.
\begin{mdfullwidth}
\printbibliography[type=online]
\end{mdfullwidth}
\pagebreak
One of the most prominent and distinctive features of this style is the
extensive use of sidenotes.\footcite{companion,ctan,markey,aristotle:poetics} There is a wide margin to provide ample room for sidenotes and small figures. Any footnotes will automatically be converted to sidenotes.
\begin{mdfullwidth}
\printbibliography[nottype=online]
\end{mdfullwidth}
\end{document}
```

[image]
[image]

Comment: XeLateX cannot compile the document when I use \begin{mdfullwidth}
\printbibliography
\end{mdfullwidth} (error message: undefined sequence).
Yet I inserted \ usepackage {mdframed} ...? Where is the problem ?