# Header problems in fullwidth environment in tufte-book

Tags: header-footer, tufte, fullwidth

I'm working under tufte-book documentclass, and I want to have my backmatter (Bibliography, Glossary, Index and TOC) in a fullwidth environment. For this, I use the following code (example for bibliography):

```
\documentclass[symmetric,justified,marginals=raggedouter]{tufte-book}
\begin{document}
\backmatter
\newgeometry{left=1in,right=1in}
\bibliographystyle{plain-fr}
\bibliography{sample-handout}
\clearpage
\restoregeometry

\end{document}
```

Unfortunatly, the headers go outside the page margins as follows:
[image]

I tried the following code, proposed in the answer of the question [Bibliography on multiple pages](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/251698/bibliography-on-multiple-pages) :

```
\documentclass[symmetric,justified,marginals=raggedouter]{tufte-book}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}
\begin{document}
\begin{tcolorbox}[enhanced, breakable, colback=white, colframe=white, check odd page, toggle left and right, grow to right by=\marginparwidth+\marginparsep, toggle enlargement=evenpage]
\bibliography{sample-handout}
\bibliographystyle{plain-fr}
\end{tcolorbox}
\end{document}
```

But it doesn't work well as the headers remain those of the previous chapter, and not those of the Bibliography !

Who can help me ?

Comment: Have you tried this here: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/46298/printing-bibliography-with-biblatex-in-tufte-handout-fullwidth-environment

Comment: I don't understant why, but \printbibliography is an undefined control sequence... so it doesn't work.

Comment: Oh, you you need to use BibLaTeX for that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution which works until now only for the bibliography chapter (the use of tcolorbox does not seems to work for Index, Glossary and TOC as I think modifications are needed in the preambule to allow it, but I don't know how to fix the problem...). This is the code to obtain the following result:

```
\documentclass[nobib,twoside,symmetric,justified,marginals=raggedouter]{tufte-book}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage[backend=biber,style=authoryear-icomp]{biblatex}
\makeatletter
\newbibmacro*{adtcite}{%
  \iffieldundef{shorthand}
    {\ifthenelse{\ifciteibid\AND\NOT\iffirstonpage}
       {\usebibmacro{cite:ibid}}
       {\iffieldequals{namehash}{\cbx@lasthash}
          {\setunit{\compcitedelim}}
          {\printnames{labelname}%
           \setunit*{\printdelim{nameyeardelim}}%
           \printlabeldateextra
           \setunit*{\printdelim{nametitledelim}}%
           \savefield{namehash}{\cbx@lasthash}}%
        \usebibmacro{cite:title}}}%
    {\usebibmacro{cite:shorthand}%
     \usebibmacro{cite:reinit}}%
      \setunit{\multicitedelim}}
\makeatother

\newbibmacro*{cite:title}{%
  \printtext[bibhyperref]{\printfield[citetitle]{labeltitle}}}

\DeclareCiteCommand{\fadtcite}[\mkbibfootnote]
  {\usebibmacro{cite:init}%
   \usebibmacro{prenote}}
  {\usebibmacro{citeindex}%
   \usebibmacro{adtcite}}
  {}
  {\usebibmacro{cite:postnote}}

\DeclareMultiCiteCommand{\fadtcites}[\mkbibfootnote]{\fadtcite} 
   {\setunit{\multicitedelim}}

\DeclareAutoCiteCommand{fadt}{\fadtcite}{\fadtcites}

\ExecuteBibliographyOptions{autocite=fadt}


\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}

\defbibenvironment{bibliography}
  {\list{}{\parsep\bibparsep}}
  {\endlist}
  {\item}   

\AtEveryBibitem{\hskip-\bibhang}
\addbibresource{sample-handout.bib}

\defbibheading{bibintoc}[\bibname]{%
  \chapter*{#1}\markboth{#1}{}%
}

\PassOptionsToPackage{hyphens}{url}

\usepackage{glossaries}
\makeglossaries
\defglsentryfmt[main]{\glsgenentryfmt\ifglsused{\glslabel}{}{*}}
\usepackage{imakeidx}

\usepackage{adjmulticol,tikz}
\makeindex[name=piece,title={Index des \oe uvres},columns=2]
\makeindex[title=Index,columns=2]


\newcommand{\full}[1]{\begin{adjmulticols}{1}{0cm}{\dimexpr-\marginparwidth- 
\marginparsep\relax}
#1
\end{adjmulticols}}

\begin{document}

\backmatter

\printbibheading[heading=bibintoc]
\begin{tcolorbox}[enhanced, breakable, colback=white, colframe=white, check odd page, toggle left and right, grow to right by=\marginparwidth+\marginparsep, toggle enlargement=evenpage]

\printbibliography[nottype=misc, heading=subbibintoc, title=Sources bibliographiques]
\printbibliography[type=misc, heading=subbibintoc, title= Sources internet]
\end{tcolorbox}

\printglossaries
\clearpage

\printindex
\clearpage

\printindex[piece]
\clearpage

\tableofcontents
\clearpage

\end{document}
```

The figure shows the result: it is possible to have a fullwidth environment for bibliography in a tufte-book documentclass, with good headers and footers:
[image]