# Longtable headings doesn't appear with fullwidth package

Tags: margins, longtable, fullwidth

I'm writing a document with long and wide tables spilling over the margin area in a two side document class. I'm using the [Marco Daniel](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/5239/marco-daniel)'s `fullwidth` package.

Using `longtable` (and even `longtabu`) the tables correctly 'runs' over the margin but, the headings and footers unexpectedly disappears. This is a MWE:

```
\documentclass[twoside,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage[inner=1in, width=345pt]{geometry}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{array}  
\usepackage{fullwidth}

\newlength{\tablewidth}
\setlength{\tablewidth}{\textwidth}
\addtolength{\tablewidth}{1in}

\begin{document}
\lipsum[1-2] 

\begin{fullwidth}[outermargin=-1in]
  \begin{longtable}{p{0.5\tablewidth}p{0.5\tablewidth}}
    \toprule
    Loren & Ipsum\\
    \midrule
    \endhead
    \lipsum[1] & \lipsum[2]\\ \midrule
    \lipsum[3] & \lipsum[4]\\ \midrule
    \lipsum[5] & \lipsum[6]\\ 
    \bottomrule
  \end{longtable}
\end{fullwidth}

\lipsum[5]

\begin{longtable}{p{0.5\tablewidth}p{0.5\tablewidth}}
  \toprule
  This & Works\\
  \midrule
  \endhead
  \lipsum[1] & \lipsum[2]\\ \midrule
  \lipsum[3] & \lipsum[4]\\ \midrule
  \lipsum[5] & \lipsum[6]\\ 
  \bottomrule
\end{longtable}
\end{document}
```

I'm also tried Marco's `mdframded` solution posted [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/34368/how-to-switch-between-two-margin-sizes), but headings still doesn't appear.

Any ideas?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `fullwidth` does nothing here. It seems that you are looking for a new feature of  `longtable`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is a solution. We don't use `fullwidth` package since it can do nothing here.

The idea is to patch `\LT@output` command (special output used by `longtable`) we move the table to the left, in fact we need to do that only for even page but we make it possible for odd pages too.

```
\documentclass[twoside,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage[inner=1in, width=345pt]{geometry}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{array} 


\newlength{\tablewidth}
\setlength{\tablewidth}{\textwidth}
\addtolength{\tablewidth}{1in}

%%--------------------------
\usepackage{etoolbox}

\newcommand{\LTemove}{1in}%  move longtable in even pages
\newcommand{\LTomove}{0in}%  move longtable in odd pages

\makeatletter
\patchcmd{\LT@output}%
{\global\vsize\@colht}%
{\global\vsize\@colht%
\ifodd\c@page\moveleft\LTomove\else\moveleft\LTemove\fi}{}{}

\patchcmd{\LT@output}%
{\setbox\@cclv\vbox{\unvbox\@cclv\copy\LT@foot\vss}}%
{\setbox\@cclv\vbox{\unvbox\@cclv\copy\LT@foot\vss}%
\setbox\@cclv\vbox{\ifodd\c@page\moveleft\LTomove\else\moveleft\LTemove\fi\box\@cclv}}{}{}
\makeatother
%%------------
\begin{document}
\lipsum[1-2] 
 \begin{longtable}{p{0.5\dimexpr\tablewidth-4\tabcolsep\relax}p{0.5\dimexpr\tablewidth-4\tabcolsep\relax}}
    \toprule
    Loren & Ipsum\\
    \midrule
    \endhead
    \lipsum[1] & \lipsum[2]\\ \midrule
    \lipsum[3] & \lipsum[4]\\ \midrule
    \lipsum[5] & \lipsum[6]\\ 
    \bottomrule
  \end{longtable}
\lipsum[5]


\begin{longtable}{p{0.5\dimexpr\tablewidth-4\tabcolsep\relax}p{0.5\dimexpr\tablewidth-4\tabcolsep\relax}}
  \toprule
  This & Works\\
  \midrule
  \endhead
  \lipsum[1] & \lipsum[2]\\ \midrule
  \lipsum[3] & \lipsum[4]\\ \midrule
  \lipsum[5] & \lipsum[6]\\ 
  \bottomrule
\end{longtable}
\end{document}
```

[image]

---

[image]

Comment: If a table starts in the middle of a page, this seems to move the entire page rather than just the table. Any way to avoid that?

Comment: using this solution in `book` class with `twoside` option produces correct results on odd pages while on even pages the table goes inside the right margin. anyway to make it work for the book class?