# full width longtable in tufte-book, like table* environment

Tags: longtable, tufte, pandoc

I am using pandoc to create a tufte-book latex.
pandoc's tables are rendered using the longtable environment.

Within tufte-book this only uses the \textwidth. Wrapping it in a fullwidth environment has no effect, because it is a float.

Using table* and tabular environments allows me to get fullwidth tables, but redefining lontable to use that, looses other longtable features.

Ideas to resolve that or to provide longtable with an option to render fullwidth or not?

Comment: if long table is shorter than one page, you can put it inside `table*` environment.

Comment: Maybe the following yould be useful for you: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/289563/134144

Comment: hacking two commands to insert \begin{table*} before and \end{table*} after works for me now. Will try second way, when I get to content where the table will be longer than a page.