# adjustwidth, but automatically switching margins

Tags: margins, geometry

Is there an existing package that does the same thing as `adjustwidth` from `changepage`, but automatically switches inner and outer margins?

MWE:

```
\documentclass[twoside]{book} 
\usepackage{multicol} 
\usepackage{changepage} 
\usepackage{lipsum} 
\usepackage{showframe} 
\begin{document} 
\lipsum 
\begin{adjustwidth}{}{-7pc} 
\lipsum[3-56] 
\end{adjustwidth} 
\end{document}
```

The above document will always place extend the margins to the *right* by -7pc, for text within the `adjustwidth` environment.

If I use the `adjustwidth*` environment instead, then

- If environment **starts** on an even page, then it will extend the margin to the **left** for the entire duration (since that is the local "outer margin" at the start of the enviornment)
- If environment **starts** on an odd page, then it will extend the margin to the **right** for the entire duration.

What I want is an environment that extends always to the correct outer margin when the environment crosses page boundaries.

Comment: It is rather hard to understand your  question, especially with reference to "not new page" as your image shows a complete 2 page spread, with no margin change mid page. It is impossible to debug an image, it always helps if you provide a complete small test document and describe how you want the output to change.

Comment: Please find my MWE example file is as follows, in this case I need extend outer margin 7pc both side(without starting newpage): \documentclass{book}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{changepage}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{showframe}
\begin{document}

\lipsum

\begin{adjustwidth}{-7pc}{0pc}
\lipsum[3-56]
\end{adjustwidth}

\end{document}

Comment: For what it is worth: there's an analogous command from KOMA (accessible using the `scrextend` package). It has the advantage that, when you run across a page boundary, it tells you: "A `addmargin*` environment starting on page 2 ends on page 10. This will result in potential wrong margins on  every other page.   So maybe you should change the `addmargin*`  environment, that ends on input line 10."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This problem was solved by the [`fullwidth`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/fullwidth) package, which was developed in response to the [similar question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/34368/how-to-switch-between-two-margin-sizes) asked here on TeX.SE.

The documentation for the package is a bit sparse, and so it took me a bit of experimenting to figure out how to get the effect you want.

Try the following:

```
\documentclass[twoside]{book} 
\usepackage{multicol} 
\usepackage{fullwidth}
\usepackage{lipsum} 
\usepackage{showframe} 
\begin{document} 
\lipsum 
\begin{fullwidth}[outermargin=-7pc, width=\linewidth+7pc]
\lipsum[3-56] 
\end{fullwidth} 
\end{document}
```

Comment: No, it adjust width one page inner margin and another page outside margin, I need both margin should be extend outer side.

Comment: @RajeshN: I updated the answer, this one should work.

Comment: Yes, yes it works, Thank you very much Willie Wong.