# Extend text to the margins on twoside documents

Tags: margins, double-sided

I am working on a two-sided article with outer margins, and I would like to have an environment that stretches the main text block to the margins.

I have come up with something using the `adjustwith*` environment of the [`changepage`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/changepage) package; however when going to a new page, the environment doesn't consider the margin side change.

Here is my MWE:

```
\documentclass[twoside]{article}

\usepackage[marginparwidth= 80pt, showframe]{geometry}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{changepage}

\begin{document}

\lipsum[1-3]

\begin{adjustwidth*}{0pt}{-\marginparwidth}
    \lipsum
\end{adjustwidth*}

\lipsum[1]

\end{document}
```

It produces the following document:

[image: first page, the environment does what I want]

[image: second page, the environment doesn't extent to the left margin but still protrudes on the right]

On the second page, I would like to have the text extend to the left margin and not protrude on the right.

Comment: Look at this: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/516925/adjustwidth-but-automatically-switching-margins

Comment: Thank you, exactly what i was looking for!