# fullwidth environment doesn't work across pages

Tags: indentation, double-sided, tufte

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to switch between two margin sizes?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/34368/how-to-switch-between-two-margin-sizes)

As a young in LaTeX days now trying to find a solution to my problem. I try to use fullwidth command at `tufte-book` but because the text exceeds a page or two does not work. The only thing close to what I  looking is [How to switch between two different marginparwidth size?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/6402/how-to-switch-between-two-different-marginparwidth-size) but again not what I want. Many many hours of research and nothing. I think and others will have the same problem please for some help

Thank you all for your immediate responses. Ι move a little late because I am new in latex and  in English language. I trying to install mdframed under ubuntu to taste it. Here a small example of the problem:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,symmetric,twoside,nofonts,justified,marginals=raggedouter]{tufte-book}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{multicol}


\begin{document}
 \lipsum[1-3]
\begin{fullwidth}

\begin{multicols}{2}
 \lipsum[1-5]
\end{multicols}

\end{fullwidth}

\end{document}
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx) Please add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-told-i-have-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) that illustrates your problem.

Comment: Perhaps consider an [`mdframed`](http://ctan.org/pkg/mdframed) alternative to the `fullwidth` environment as suggested by the package author himself: [How to switch between two margin sizes?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/34368/how-to-switch-between-two-margin-sizes)

Comment: I thought I have exactly the same issue in http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/34368/how-to-switch-between-two-margin-sizes. How is this different?

Comment: I installed the programs mdframed and etoolbox I tried, not exactly what I want to do, unless I do not understand something. That I want is to use the  two columns and fullwidth environment  and continuity in more than two pages without having to intervene. When I use  your directive   with two columns  environment  produces overflow error as shown in the example code
additionally I don't want to fix myself the margins, but i want  the margins are the same as those specified in tufte-book